# Using std::format when importing <iostream> and <format> at the same time caused a SIGSEGV fault

Tags: c++, iostream, stdformat

I used `g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++23` to compile a formatted "Hello Module!" but got SIGSEGV fault by calling `std::format`. If I didn't import `<iostream>` and then replace `std::cout << format;` with `printf(format.data());` everything works well.

```
import <iostream>;
import <format>;

int main()
{
    std::string format = std::format("Hello {}!\n", "Module");
    std::cout << format;
    return 0;
}
```

GDB backtrace:

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ff6039f8d60 in std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >::begin (this=0x5ff800) at D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:190
190           { return this->_M_str; }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ff6039f8d60 in std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >::begin (this=0x5ff800) at D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:190
#1  0x00007ff6039f1a31 in std::basic_format_parse_context<char>::basic_format_parse_context (this=0x5ff958, __fmt="Hello {}!", __num_args=18446744073709551615)
    at D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/format:206
#2  0x00007ff6039f1b20 in std::__format::_Scanner<char>::_Scanner (this=0x5ff950, __str="Hello {}!", __nargs=18446744073709551615)
    at D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/format:3434
#3  0x00007ff6039f1b74 in std::__format::_Formatting_scanner<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char>::_Formatting_scanner (this=0x5ff950, __fc=..., __str="Hello {}!")
    at D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/format:3548
#4  0x00007ff603a04686 in std::__format::__do_vformat_to<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char, std::basic_format_context<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char> > (
    __out=..., __fmt="Hello {}!", __args=std::format_args with 1 argument, __loc=0x0) at D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/format:3650
#5  0x00007ff603a077f9 in std::vformat_to<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char> > (__args=std::format_args with 1 argument, __fmt="Hello {}!", __out=...)
    at D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/format:3681
#6  std::vformat (__fmt="Hello {}!", __args=std::format_args with 1 argument) at D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/format:3708
#7  0x00007ff603a075b3 in std::format<char const (&) [7]> (__fmt=...) at D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/format:3743
#8  0x00007ff6039f1bd3 in main () at .\module.cpp:6
```

`__nargs` being UINT64_MAX seems to be weird.

I wonder if it's a bug of module feature, or, how to fixed this.

Comment: Note that those aren't the way to import the c++23 standard library modules https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library